# How to disable file download popup in Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2003, file-download

I was able to [disable `file download` popup in all popular browsers](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/File+Downloads) except Internet Explorer.

This is the popup:

[image: File Download popup]

I thought this would do it, but I still get the popup:

Internet Explorer -> menu *Tools* -> *Internet Options* -> *Security* -> select zone (example: Internet) -> *Security levels for this zone* -> Custom level... -> *Downloads* -> *File download* -> *Automatic prompting for file downloads* -> Disable -> *OK* -> *Yes* -> *OK*.

I am not interested in automating the popup, I do not want it to appear.

The OS is [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003), Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Let me begin by summarizing 3 methods that did NOT work:  

  **FIRST**  Internet Options > Security > Custom Level > uncheck Automatic Prompting for file Downloads  

  **SECOND**  Folder Options > File Types > Advance > Uncheck the check box for prompt on Download

  **THIRD**  Registry > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
Internet Settings\Zones\\*\1803 > Change to 0 or 3

Comment: Your fix only disables Automatic Prompting for Downloads if the user did not initiate the download, i.e., if it was initiated from the webpage. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What do you want it to do when you click on a file URL, instead of prompting to download? Just download the file directly?

Comment: Yes, just download the file, like all other browsers do.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem now. I hope the following information would help you:

**Solution 1**

Open Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security :
**Clear** the 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk'.

[image: Clear the 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk']

**Solution 2**

Open Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom level > Download :
Select **Disable** for 'Automatic prompting for file download'.
Repeat this for all 4 zones.

[image: Disable automatic prompting for file download]

**Solution 3**

Open My Computer > Tools > Folder Options > File Types > PDF > Advanced :
**Clear** the 'Confirm open after download'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/289772/automatically-download-files-in-internet-explorer-without-getting-prompted-to-sav) SU question *might* be similar to yours

You can use the addon iMacros. 
From the original question's answer:

> > ... Internet explorer automatically downloads the file into a directory I choose without asking?
>
> You can use the **free** iMacros for Internet Explorer addon. It supports download automation via >the ONDOWNLOAD command (just record the download sequence, then replay it via iMacros. It is a >macro recorder for the web browser.
>
> http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/

Comment: Thank you for your introduction to iMacros. I know that Željko Filipin has also posted AutoIt scripts for automating the clicking of the File Download Dialogue. Just one thing: I am not interested in automating the popup, I do not want it to appear.

Comment: Aha. Alright - sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start->Run->gpedit.msc

Double-click the “Turn off the Security Settings Check Feature” entry and choose “Enable 
[image]

Explanation: This policy setting turns off the Security Settings Check feature, which checks Internet Explorer security settings to determine when the settings put Internet Explorer at risk. ( NOTE: this means that the annoying bar will not pop up) NO MORE ANNOYING INFORMATION BAR!!! If you enable this policy setting, the security settings check will not be performed. If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, the security settings check will be performed.

Reghack if you don't want to do it via gpedit

Open regedit (Start > Run > regedit )
- Navigate to HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Security

- If those key don't exist, you'll probably have to create them. They are case-sensitive.
- Create the following DWORD (case sensitive) DisableSecuritySettingsCheck
- Give this DWORD the value: 1

[Source](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Disable-Annoying-Information-Bar_t19272.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, but it looks to me that you are talking about disabling information bar. I want to disable `File Download` popup.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the info bar, sorry. Do you mean the dialog box?, Run, Save, Cancel?

Comment: Yes, popup with the title "File download". (Take a look at the link in my question for screen shot.) I want to click a link to a file and have the file downloaded to my machine without any popups.

Comment: I think you would need a download manager to do this, I know of no way to do it in windows IE natively.

Comment: Isn't that strange? :) I was able to disable the popup in all other browsers.

Comment: I would try an IE reset, Internet Options>Advanced Tab>Reset, then try to disable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file when prompted to "Open or Save"
When complete, click on the View downloads button at the bottom of the page
Right click the file that was downloaded
Uncheck "Always ask before opening this type of file"
This is per file type. Not for everything. You may want to consider the security risks if prompted to download, executables for example.
Hope this helps!