# Automatically download files in Internet Explorer without getting prompted to Save / Cancel?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-7

I am currently using IE7 with XP SP3.

When a webpage download with unknown file type loads, I get a prompt asking me what I want to do with the file. My options are FIND SAVE CANCEL.

How do I make it so that I don't get this popup prompt, but Internet explorer automatically downloads the file into a directory I choose without asking?

PS. I have already tried Tools >> Internet Options >> Security >> Internet >> Custom Level >> Downloads >> Disable/Enable/Enable, but this doesn't help.

---

Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have to use IE. I'm using it in connection with other proprietary software based on IE and its settings. And yes I'm aware it's not a great browser. (This is not for strictly personal use in the browsing sense. )

Comment: Are you asking this question as an end user or a developer?

Comment: I am a developer, but asking the question as an end user pretty much.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but U am looking to do the same thing. How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Clear the 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk'.

Ensure you have set your default download location.

Answer (score 0):

> ... Internet explorer automatically downloads the file into a directory I choose without asking?

You can use the **free** iMacros for Internet Explorer addon. It supports download automation via the ONDOWNLOAD command (just record the download sequence, then replay it via iMacros. It is a macro recorder for the web browser.

http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/