# How to schedule a download only to start at a particular time?

Tags: windows, download-manager, file-download

Our Satellite internet provider gives us "unlimited browsing" between 11pm and 7pm. As we have a very limited bandwidth in the day and the download is reasonably large, other than staying up late is there any way I could schedule the download as to only start at 11pm? I was thinking a PowerShell command might be possible (but I have no idea how to achieve this) or maybe a GUI alternative.

I have tried Windows Task Scheduler but although I could get the browser to open I didn't know how I could make the download start itself.

I am running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think any decent download manager has this feature... Googling it, the second result I found is [free download manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/index.htm), free and open source, and the feature list mentions "powerful scheduler", so I guess that would do.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a scheduled task. If you must, you can type it into a powershell window, but it will also work from cmd.exe console.

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Late Night Download" /TR “C:\Downloader.ps1” /ST 23:00
```

or try it's GUI.

taskschd.msc.

Downloader.ps1

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7z920.msi" "C:\Temp\7z920.msi" -Description "Late Night Download" -DisplayName "Unlimited Browsing after 11pm"
```

Comment: Sure, you could start a downloader with the items to download already set to go. many downloaders will "resume" when thier program is started back up again, so I wont recommend a specific one.

Comment: will you explain more the commands you are using, I mainly mean how to customize it to just start all of the scheduled downloads for any download manager

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

- Create the download in your download manager.
- While it is still downloading, exit it, don't pause.
- Schedule it to start after 11pm using scheduled task or any third party software.

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to run the browser when you want (just make sure the browser is pointing at the downloading file, not the web page!)

I suggest you use FireFox as you can set it to automatically save files and not be prompted:

```
orange Firefox button (or Tools menu) > Options > General > "Saves files to"
```

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/957427)

For IE, there are a [few options listed here on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer)