# How to configure internet explorer to block download prompt for csv files

Tags: internet-explorer, csv, prompt

How to configure internet explorer to avoid save or cancel prompt while downloading .csv file and download the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Internet Explorer version. If you're using IE8 and down then the easiest way is to download a csv file one time and then uncheck the 'Always ask before...' checkbox.
For IE9 and up, you should:

1. Launch Registry Editor (`Start >> Run >> regedit.exe`)
2. Expand `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`
4. If it doesn’t exist, create the `AttachmentExecute` key
5. Create the `{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` key
6. Create a new Binary Value with the Name `Excel.CSV`*
7. Re-launch IE and test – should be now working ok

*In order to know the name of the binary value you should run at command prompt the command `assoc.csv`, in my case it was `Excel.CSV`

I got to this answer from several places, mostly from [here](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save), but if it still doesn't work I'd try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer?lq=1) thread.

Answer (score 0):

I recently (4-Nov-2015) found that other Group Policies (I don't know which ones; but my project had two different enterprise groups stop auto launching) will disable the auto launch even if the {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\ registry entry is in place. To once again regain the auto launch behavior, you have to White-List the application as well. To do this: 
 - Create a new Binary Value with the Name: `Application\<executable_name.exe>` 
To continue the above example, you would add the executable for Excel or `Application\excel.exe` as a new Binary value. 
 **NOTE:** `Application` is not a key. It is simply part of the name. 
 I wish I could point to research or documentation on this. This solution was only found by using Microsoft's Process Monitor (procmon) and noticing that the `Application\<executable_name.exe>` name was queried in close proximity to the {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} query. Even after I found the `Application` White-List element, I still could not find a reference. If someone can find an actual reference, please add it to one of these answers.