# How to automatically download exe files in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, group-policy, security-warning, security-policy

In **IE 11** and before downloading files there's the annoying bar (as seen [here](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/) under Internet Explorer 9 & 10).

I've been trying to disable it for a while... I tried enabling in gpedit.msc `Turn off the Security Settings Check feature` and tried adding a binary value `exefile` in the registry at: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` but that doesn't work.

I don't want to use an add-on since I need to simulate a user and just skip that bar. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

**BTW**: The binary value `exefile` is because I checked in the cmd for `assoc .exe` which gave `.exe=exefile`.

**EDIT**: Another thing important to notice is that in IE11 there's no 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk' in: Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security like in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer?lq=1) thread.

Comment: Do you mean your users don't have this box appear? Not only does this box provide you options when downloading a file it provides a level of security, in that a site can't run a script to download hidden files when you click an innocent looking button.

Comment: No, What I mean is that I'm **simulating** a user so I need to skip that bar. (I know the files that will be downloaded in advance)